# Random forest algorithms able to switch data sets

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I'm curious as to whether research been done into random forests that combine unsupervised with supervised learning in a way allowing a single algorithm to find patterns in, and work with, multiple different data sets. I have googled every possible way to find research on this, and have come up empty. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note: I have already asked this question in the Data Sciences forum, but it's basically a dead forum so I came here.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. How exactly do you want to combine unsupervised and supervised methods?

Comment: I want to find if anyone has tried ANY method of combining the two with the **express purpose of creating an algorithm that can handle multiple data sets** without having to "spoon-feed" each one to the machine.

Normally with ML, (as I understand it) data scientists have to delineate each separate variable in a data set so the algorithm can then use those attributes/variables to classify the data for future use.

Comment: In principle, random forests can handle any number of different data sets. You just need features and labels to predict. For unsupervised methods, you still need the features. I don't know what you mean with your question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if my comments are too vague.  Has there been an attempt to create a program that can automatically handle multiple data sets (labels, features, everything) without (much) human intervention?

Comment: Again, as long as you define features and labels, this is true for any classification algorithm. You need to define "handle" and "human intervention" if you want a more definitive answer.

Comment: Ok so what I meant by human intervention is actually applying labels.  I was wondering if there are any projects where you can feed the machine 10,000 photos of cats and dogs, and the machine can find patterns in those pictures.  Then, without changing code or doing anything, feed the same algorithm 10,000 hospital bills (or whatever) and the same algorithm can find patterns by itself.  Kind of a universal data classifier.

Comment: What you describe is called unsupervised learning, specifically it sounds like pattern mining.

Comment: Thank you Lars, I will try and look into pattern mining.  You've given me something to Google haha.  If you make an answer like the last comment, I will accept it so this question gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(also read the comments and will incorporate the content in my answer)

From what I read between the lines is that you want to use Deep networks in a transfer learning setting. However, this would not be based on decision trees. 
http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v27/mesnil12a/mesnil12a.pdf

There are many elements in your question:

1.) Machine learning algorithms, in general, don't care about the source of your data set. So basically you can feed the learning algorithms 20 different data sets and it will use all of them. However, the data should have the same underlying concept (except in the transfer learning case see below). This means: if you combine cats/dogs data with bills data this will not work or make it much harder for the algorithms. At least all input features need to be identical (exceptions exists), e.g, it is hard to combine images with text.

2.) **labeled/unlabeled**: Two important terms: a data set is a set of data points with a fixed number of dimensions. Datapoint i might be described as {Xi1,....Xin} where each Xi might for example be a pixel. A label Yi is from another domain, e.g., cats and dogs

3.) **unsupervised learning** data without any labels. (I have the gut feeling that this is not what you want.

4.) **semi-supervised** learning: The idea is basically that you combine data where you have labels with data without labels. Basically you have a set of images labeled as cats and dogs {Xi1,..,Xin,Yi} and a second set which contains images with cats/dogs but no labels {Xj1,..,Xjn}. The algorithm can use this information to build better classifiers as the unlabeld data provide information on how images look in general.

3.) **transfer learning** (I think this come closest to what you want). The Idea is that you provide a data set of cats and dogs and learn a classifier. Afterwards you want to train the classifier with images of cats/dogs/hamster. The training does not need to start from scratch but can use the cats/dogs classifier to converge much faster

4.) **feature generation** / **feature construction** The idea is that the algoritm learns features like "eyes".  This features are used in the next step to learn the classifier.  I'm mainly aware of this in the context of **deep learning**. Where the algoritm learns in the first step concepts like edges and constructs increasingly complex features like faces cats intolerant it can describe things like "the man on the elephant. *This combined with transfer learning is probably what you want. However deep learning is based on Neural networks besides a few exceptions.*

5.) **outlier detection** you provide a data set of cats/dogs as known images. When you provide the cats/dogs/hamster classifier. The classifier tells you that it has never seen something like a hamster before.

6.) **active learning**  The idea is that you don't provide labels for all examples (Data points) beforehand, but that the algorithms asks you to label certain data points. This way you need to label much less data.